# FileMaker Pro 11: Modify database and import data from user copy

Tags: import, export, filemaker

I'm starting to make some changes to a FileMaker Pro 11 database for a customer. It's my first job on a FileMaker db. 
I need to work on the copy I got and after the work is completed, I'll have to import the data from the working (customer's) copy replacing the data in the new version of the database.
I'm trying to use the FileMaker "Import Records -> File" menu. So I assumed I could import from data from the working copy. But I only get the option to:

1. Add New Records (that appends the imported records as new)
2. Update existing records (but this, if I understood correctly would not
   delete records that have been deleted in the working copy, but only
   update the existing ones)
3. Update matching records

None of this option seems to actually replace the data in the target database.
Is there any other option that I can't find?

Comment: This is not a programming question. [superUser](http://superuser.com) might be a better place to ask.

Comment: I appreciate your opinion. But since it is task related to development (and looking at the number of questions about Filemaker on otackoverflow), this seems to be the right place. I think the -1 is a bit unfair. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are more records in the new copy of the database update existing records should work for you. New Record 1 will replace Old Record 1. New Record 2 will replace Old Record 2, etc. No matching is occurring on the records, so if a record was deleted in the New data the following record from the New data will now overwrite the Old data.

More here: http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/import_export.16.10.html

The other way to overwrite everything is to simply Delete All Records and then import with Add New Records.

You'll want to think about any automatically-generated indexes that the records have to make certain that you are doing the right thing. A few practice migrations will really help clarify what needs to be done. Even better, you may be able to script the data migration after you've done it by hand once or twice.

Answer (score 0):

Check the found set of your source database, you may only be importing the current found set into the destination, which looks like nothing is happening.